# How to merge only one commit to master and not all commits of a branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches named `dev` and `master`. Currently the commits looks like the following:

```
dev    master
---    ------
A       A
B       B
C       
D
E
```

Now I want to merge only commit `E` to branch `master`. So here would be the expected result:

```
dev    master
---    ------
A       A
B       B
C       E
D
E
```

Any idea how can I do that?

---

Also how should I manage to be able merge commits `C`, `D` later to branch `master` for being fully sync.

Comment: Try `git checkout mater; git cherry-pick E`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

At first, `E` shouldn't depend either `C` or `D`. Otherwise, you probably will have to solve some conflicts or you will be in a state that is not complete.

Problems generally have one more solution. I will try to offer some.

### 1. Cherry Pick

```
A--B(master)--C--D--E(dev)
```

Create a branch where `master` branch points: `git checkout -b topic master`

```
A--B(master, topic)--C--D--E(dev)
```

Cherry pick commit `E`: `git cherry-pick E`

```
A--B(master)--C--D--E(dev)
     \
      E'(topic)
```

Merge `topic` branch into the `master` branch: `git checkout master` `git merge topic`

```
A--B--C--D--E(dev)
     \
      E'(master, topic)
```

At this point, if you rebase `dev` branch onto `master` branch, `E` commit will be disappeared because they are(should be) the same: `git checkout dev` `git rebase master`

```
A--B--E'(master)--C--D(dev)
```

### 2. Interactive Rebase

```
A--B(master)--C--D--E(dev)
```

Interactive rebase `dev` branch onto `master` branch and move `E` commit at before `C` commit: `git checkout dev` `git rebase -i master`

```
A--B(master)--E--C--D(dev)
```

Create a branch where `E` commit points: `git checkout -b topic E`

```
A--B(master)--E(topic)--C--D(dev)
```

Merge `topic` branch into `master` branch: `git checkout master` `git merge topic`

```
A--B--E(master)--C--D(dev)
```

### 3. Rebase --onto

```
A--B(master)--C--D--E(dev)
```

Create a branch where `dev` points: `git checkout -b topic dev`

```
A--B(master)--C--D--E(dev, topic)
```

Run `git rebase --onto B D topic`

```
A--B(master)--C--D--E(dev)
     \
      E'(topic)
```

At this point, if you rebase `dev` branch onto `master` branch, `E` commit will be disappeared because they are(should be) the same: `git checkout dev` `git rebase master`

```
A--B--E'(master)--C--D(dev)
```